# Docker container didnt restart on "unless-stopped"

Tags: python-3.x, docker

I have a ETL process running Docker container on python. The container configuration has `restart: unless-stopped` policy.

I have a exception handling for my python code, but the code ran into exception block and caught another exception and container didnt get restarted.

I tried to do a nested exception, but not sure if this is going to work and also how `restart: unless-stopped` will handle nested exceptions.

Here is my code

```
def main():
    return some_function()

def some_function():
    try:
         
        ...
        ...
        # some code which could caught exception (tried with raising AttributeError)
         
    except Exception as main_exception:
        try:
            # some more code which could cause exception (tried with raising AttributeError)
        except Exception as nested_exception:
            print('Failed to handle exception: ', str(nested_exception))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    exit(main())
```

Does this going to restart the container always, is it a right way to handle? Can somebody help me to understand the restart policy for docker?

Comment: Docker won't restart the container if the process doesn't exit, right? So you need to exit the process to restart the container, maybe with `sys.exit(1)`? I'm no Docker expert but that's what it seems to me.

Comment: So that means when the process crash with exception, it has exited improperly, but its supposed to be exit gracefully. I mean the nested exception will work, right?

Comment: You caught the exceptions, so they were never thrown. After you caught them, after the `print` in the code you posted, what did you do? Did you exit the process, or continue doing something else?

Comment: it got exit with the function named `main()`, that is  `exit(main())`

Comment: So is the code excerpt from the function `main()`? If so, did you `return` after you caught the inner exception, to exit the process?

Comment: I updated the code above in description. Its approximately like this

Comment: OK, so it seems that after the `print` call, your process would exit. What does Docker say? Does it maybe show that the process exited, and restarted it? Or does it just show that the process is stopped? Also Docker [docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#restart-policy-details) says containers are only restarted if they ran for 10 seconds or longer. Maybe that's the issue?